# Extract last characters of a string in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following set of data.  I need to extract the single character of 'C' into another column.  It's not always going to be the letter 'C'.

I also need to extract the numbers 105, 120, 8 and etc into a separate column.  Here's what I tried, but not sure how to figure this with multiple spaces in the string.   `=RIGHT(A12,LEN(A12)-FIND(" ",A12))`
This formula only gives me `01202017 C 105`.

```
AAPL 01202017 C 105
AAPL 01202017 C 120
ABX 01202017 C 8
AMD 01202017 C 2.5
CLVS 01202017 C 40
```

Thanks,

Comment: is it always 4 items in the string and you want the third and fourth?

Comment: You could always use text to columns, split it on the space, then delete the first two columns.

Comment: That's correct.  I always want the third and fourth items in the string, but in separate columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Text to columns would do it quickly, but if you want a formula then use this:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMN(B:B)*999,999))
```

copy it over one column and down the dataset.

[image]

Comment: This is really amazing.  Thank you.  I'll have one additional question, but I'll post another.

Answer (score 0):

`= Mid(A1, Search(" ? ", A1) + 1, 1)` for the letter and

`= Mid(A1, Search(" ? ", A1) + 3, 99)` for the number.

`Search` is like `Find` but it also supports wildcard symbols where `?` matches any character, and `*` matches any 0 or more characters.